# Multilingual text copy/paste to Textbox in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have textbox which accepts string for File name. The user can give/type any name for textbox, even he copy text (Multilingual text) and paste in the textbox. He can copy from any source.

The issue is, how do i detect the 'Language' of copied text which is pasted in textbox and 
display the text in that corresponding language?

Answer (score 1):

There is a .net library that does the job:[ntextcat](http://ntextcat.codeplex.com/) ... and ... it`s open source.

Also, you can use [google-api-for-dotnet](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/) to the actual translate.

Answer (score 0):

May be ill think of having a common words in a dictionary for each language and looking it up when user pastes it. If i find it in any of these dictionary item, then ill know its language type. May not be the best solution your looking for. Open to experts comment here.